# Get items from a string into an array with pattern

Tags: java, string

I have a string with a bunch of latitude and longitudes like this

`LINESTRING (-79.0578544444577 43.0929133770364, -79.0559554404751 43.0929995585932, -79.0540564364926 43.09308574015, -79.0504086322323 43.0931797561892, -79.0503228015438 43.0911427096913)`

and I want to get the coordinates out of the string into an array. I know this can be done with `string splitting` but I dont understand how to write the expression to get just the coordinates from the string.

can someone help me outwith this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy having them all in one array:

```
String str = "LINESTRING (-79.0578544444577 43.0929133770364, -79.0559554404751 43.0929995585932, -79.0540564364926 43.09308574015, -79.0504086322323 43.0931797561892, -79.0503228015438 43.0911427096913)";
String[] arr = str.split("\\(|\\)")[1].split(",? ");
for (String s: arr)
   System.out.println(a);
```

`split("\\(|\\)")` means split on `(` or `)`. So that would be `{"LINESTRING ", "-79...", ""}`.

`[1]` because this is the position containing `"-79..."`.

`split(",? ")` means split on `,` followed by a space or just a space.

If you want to extract the coordinates in pairs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
{
   System.out.println("coordinate 1 = "+arr[i]);
   System.out.println("coordinate 2 = "+arr[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. substring between first `(` and last `)`
2. split on `", "` and you will get String[] array that will contain pairs like `"-79.0578544444577 43.0929133770364","-79.0559554404751 43.0929995585932",...`
3. now you can split with space `" "` on each of that pair to get another String[] array, this time containing `"-79.0578544444577", "43.0929133770364"`

---

You could also use regex to find numbers in form [optional `-`][one or two digits][dot][more than one digits]. Such pattern could look like `"-?\\d{1,2}[.]\\d+"`

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Coordinates {
   static class LatLon {
      double lat;
      double lon;
      public LatLon( double lat, double lon ) {
         this.lat = lat;
         this.lon = lon;
      }
      @Override public String toString(){ return lat + ", " + lon; }
   }
   public static void main( String[] args ){
      String info =
         "LINESTRING (" +
            "-79.0578544444577 43.0929133770364, " +
            "-79.0559554404751 43.0929995585932, " +
            "-79.0540564364926 43.09308574015, " +
            "-79.0504086322323 43.0931797561892, " +
            "-79.0503228015438 43.0911427096913)";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[^\\(]+\\(([^\\)]+).*" );
      Matcher m = p.matcher( info );
      if( m.matches()) {
         List< LatLon > coordinates = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
         String[] coords = m.group( 1 ).split( "," );
         for( int i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i ) {
            String[] latLon = coords[i].trim().split( " " );
            coordinates.add(
               new LatLon(
                  Double.parseDouble( latLon[0] ),
                  Double.parseDouble( latLon[1] )));
         }
         System.out.println( coordinates );
      }
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[-79.0578544444577, 43.0929133770364, -79.0559554404751, 43.0929995585932, -79.0540564364926, 43.09308574015, -79.0504086322323, 43.0931797561892, -79.0503228015438, 43.0911427096913]
```

Answer (score 0):

If LineString is the name of your variable and what is inside the parenthesis its value (excluding parenthesis) then :

```
String[] coords = LINESTRING.split(" ");
```

should work !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] coordinates = LINESTRING.split(",*\\s+");
```

This should immediately split both by space and by comma. This regular expression looks for zero or more commas and then one or more whitespace characters as the delimiter.